# Teradata error : select * must have from clause

Tags: sql, teradata

How can I convert this sql server query to Teradata query. This is not working in Teradata.

```
select *, 
   (select top 1 endvalue 
    from #AUID 
    where #AUID.adate <= t.adate and #AUID.tid=t.tid 
    order by #AUID.adate desc) as AsD
from History_1 t
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have simply a `*` when a subquery is involved. You should use tablename.* or alias.*(if alias is used).

```
select t.*, 
   (select top 1 endvalue 
    from #AUID 
    where #AUID.adate <= t.adate and #AUID.tid=t.tid 
    order by #AUID.adate desc) as AsD
from History_1 t
```

Still, this would throw  ***Failure 6916 TOP N Syntax error: Top N option is not supported in subquery*** error.

You can try joining the tables.

```
select
    t.*,
    a.endvalue
from 
    History_1 t
left outer join
    #AUID a
on a.tid = t.tid
and a.adate <= t.adate
qualify row_number() over (partition by t.tid, t.adate order by a.adate desc) = 1;  --this ensures you select only one row with max(adate)
```